How to handle if the fd has read and write at the same using select in winsock?
I saw some code examples to explain select() can handle multiple events at the same time as below:
FD_SET readfds;
FD_SET writefds;
FD_SET exceptfds;

FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_ZERO(&writefds);
FD_ZERO(&exceptfds);

FD_SET(someRandomSocket, &readfds);
FD_SET(someRandomSocket, &writefds);
FD_SET(someRandomSocket, &exceptfds);

timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = ...;
timeout.tv_usec = ...;

int total = select(0, &readfds, &writefds, &exceptfds, &timeout);

if (total == -1)
{
    // error in select() itself, handle as needed...
}
else if (total == 0)
{
    // timeout, handle as needed...
}
else
{
    if (FD_ISSET(someRandomSocket, &exceptfds) )
    {
        // socket has inbound OOB data, or non-blocking connect() has failed, or some other socket error, handle as needed...
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(someRandomSocket, &readfds) )
    {
        // socket has inbound data, or has disconnected gracefully, handle as needed...
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(someRandomSocket, &writefds) )
    {
        // socket is writable, or non-blocking connect() has succeeded, handle as needed...
    }
}

However, I am wondering how about if the socket has write data and read data at the same time. How can I only get the read data or the write data from the socket?
For example, if FD_ISSET(someRandomSocket, &readfds) and FD_ISSET(someRandomSocket, &writefds) are both true at the same time, if I just want to get the read data, is it possible to also get the read data when I use recv(someRandomSocket, buf, 8192, 0)? Or if I just want to send out the write data, is it possible to also send out the write data when I use send(someRandomSocket, buf, 8192, 0)?

If the socket can both be read from and written to, both flags will be set. If you want to prioritize reading, then use else if (FD_ISSET(someRandomSocket, &writefds)) instead. If you want to prioritize writing, then change the order you check.

If a socket is ready for reading or writing now and you do not interact with the socket by resp reading or sending, it will be ready for reading and/or writing again when you call select again.

@Someprogrammerdude I want to know whether it will also read wrongly the write data when I use rev() and the both flags are set. It is because the write data and the read data both exist in the socket at the same time.

Reading and writing uses different buffers. So no, if you write some data to the socket and then read, you will not read what you written. And writing will not overwrite what's in the read buffer. Reading and writing is totally separate.
